# Anyway to test kiosk mode with unpublished app?

Tags: kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

I have a Chrome app that I'd like to test in kiosk mode, but I can't seem to figure out how.

The manifest file has the kiosk mode flag set, but adding the app ID to the Manage Kiosk Apps screen doesn't work.

The app is unpublished, as it is installed directly on the ChromeBox.

Is there any way to achieve this, or am I going to have to publish it as unlisted, just for testing purposes?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same and it looks like it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2017, you cannot do this. The only solution is to publish it privately to testers. You can setup tester accounts that are the only ones able to see the app and then you'll be able to enter its ID in the "Manage Kiosk applications" screen.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

Make sure you enter this as the url:

> Enter https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx as the URL. The ID is part of the Chrome Web Store URL.  In this example, the ID is the string "lfkjhmmdoiphacoihfjjgcdcjppdogjh" in the URL:
>   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk-google-app-test/lfkjhmmdoiphacoihfjjgcdcjppdogjh

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177431?hl=en